# Redirect SQL Server Instance to a new instance?

Tags: sql-server, windows, sql-server-2008, alias

I have a web application that connects to a SQL Server named instance as `OLDSERVER\OLDINSTANCE`.  I need to redirect the traffic to `NEWSERVER\NEWINSTANCE`.  I know you can redirect SQL Server database connections using the SQL Server Client Network Utility (cliconfig.exe) with an alias, but it doesn't seem to support aliasing connections with **instances**.  Does anyone know if it's possible to redirect traffic from one instance to another?

I've tried the following with no luck:
 1. Creating an alias in SQL Server Client Network Utility (both with and without the incoming instance name -- i.e. using just the server name and then with the server name and instance)
 2. Modifying the hosts file to point to the new SQL Server.

Anyone have any ideas how to redirect instance traffic to another instance?

Comment: Perhaps could work if the new instance was installed as newserver\oldinstance

Comment: It is actually.  But that didn't work, unfortunately.

Comment: Shame, thought that would have done it. Can't test now but I'm sure I've had it working like that in the past with a DNS redirect.

Answer (score 0):

i cant comment, so i write an answer... and, why dont change the Connection String  of your application?

Comment: The reason is that the web server houses several thousand applications built by different people who were all given the connection string by my predecessor.  The connection string is located through the application and in registry settings.  It would take quite a long time to do this right.

Comment: @StatsStudent look this [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/6897f00f-8f79-4415-88f7-5b766c174f4d/dns-alias-to-named-instance?forum=sqldatabaseengine) use a DNS alias. hope this help you!